# Constant current near to maximum load current

Tags: mosfet, current, current-limiting, constant-current

Following on from my [last question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/679416/8376) where I asked about dual purposing a PFET used for reverse polarity prevention for current limiting to a load (spoiler, that doesn't work for my application), I have tried 2 ways of choking the power off to the load. The first simple schematic uses another PFET and a voltage divider to control the load power . .

[image]

This next attempt uses an op amp and a NFET to control things on the low side. Nice because it gives a constant current if the load resistive value drifts. Comes from [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa868/slaa868.pdf) application note. I'm concerned that R_set will have to take up a large physical amount of space to dissipate the power (the load will draw up to 11A - although in sub 100ms pulses). Further, if it has to dissipate a lot of power (up to 55W at 1/2 ohm) then won't R_set heat up also and then throw the system out of balance? I'm constrained on board space and also concerned about R_set being a constant. Is there a way to use the load directly as a current sense? Am I missing something about R_set that means it will not waste a lot of power? I understand this circuit is great when a small constant current is required. In my application, I want the option to trim a little power from max power so there is headroom to supply a little more current if the load gets warm to keep a constant rate of work.

[image]

Comment: How accurately do you need to control the current?  How much voltage drop across your circuit can you tolerate when the current is below your limit?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I can tolerate quite bad accuracy, like within 10%. More confused by second part of question. If the load heats to the point where its resistance is too high to pull enough current from the 48V supply (which we can assume to be near ideal), then that will always be the limiting element.

Comment: You will need to measure the current somehow. A typical way is to measure the voltage drop across a current sense resistor. A method with a lower voltage drop is to use a Hall effect device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linear circuits like these, whatever current load current is passing, it must also flow through whatever "pass" elements are employed to limit that current. In your first circuit, that's U2. In the second this is both M1 and \$R_{SET}\$.

In all such cases, the regulating element (U2, M1) regulates current by introducing some "controllable" resistance into the current path, with the consequence that this very resistance must develop a voltage across it too, according to Ohm's law.

Let's take the example of some arbitrary load, for which we "throttle" current to 10A current by introducing just such a resistance. Below left, I use a resistor to throttle current, on the right a MOSFET:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foIVWi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In both cases, the loads (R2, R3) receive 100W of power, corresponding to 10A of current through the 1Ω load, but also in both cases the "current throttling" element (R1 or M1) must resist current to some extent in order to produce this condition.

In this setup, the effective drain-to-source resistance \$R_{DS}\$ of M1 will be the same as R1, 1.4Ω. It doesn't matter whether the throttle is a fixed resistor, or a MOSFET being controlled by some clever feedback arrangement, current throttling is achieved through electrical resistance.

You may also think of the throttle element as having to "dispose" of 14V of the supply, which you see on voltmeters WM1 and VM3. In order for the load to have 10V across it (which would cause 10A to flow through it), the throttle itself must "take up" the remaining 14V. Whichever way you look at it, and whichever scheme you devise for achieving this, you will always have 14V to eat up, with 10A through it, corresponding to a power dissipation of:

$$ P = I \times V = 10A \times 14V = 140W $$

This is very inconvenient, and is why we see so many DC-DC converters in use, which can perform the same function much more efficiently, at a cost of complexity and other caveats.

Clearly, then, any approach to this problem involving linear pass elements is going to waste power in those elements, and that power must be managed somehow, with heat-sinks and fans probably.

The obvious solution is to reduce the power supply voltage, so the pass elements don't need to "drop" so much voltage, but this is only appropriate if you know the exact resistance of the load, and that resistance remains constant.

You raised the legitimate concern that \$R_{SET}\$ will dissipate 55W, but you overlooked power in M1. At 10A, \$R_{SET}\$ will have 5V across it, but poor old M1 might have 20V! M1 is also passing those same 10A of current, and  will potentially dissipate *way* more power than \$R_{SET}\$, making \$R_{SET}\$ the *least* of your problems.

In fact, you can reduce power in \$R_{SET}\$ very easily, by setting \$R_{SET}=0.1\Omega\$ and setting \$V_2\$ commensurately smaller, but whatever relief your provide to \$R_{SET}\$ is only offloading it straight onto the shoulders of M1.

Your concern that \$R_{SET}\$ might "throw the system out of balance" is not justified. The purpose of the op-amp and its control loop is to place a constant, known voltage \$V_2\$ across \$R_{SET}\$, to obtain a known current through it. The only problem posed by \$R_{SET}\$ is that the maximum possible voltage across the load is now \$V_1 - V_2\$, since \$R_{SET}\$ has "taken up" \$V_2\$ of the total \$V_1\$ available.

Your second design looks OK, M1 and \$R_{SET}\$ power aside, the maximum load current \$I\$ should be:

$$ I = \frac{V_2}{R_{SET}} = \frac{1V}{0.5\Omega} = 2A $$

If you need 11A, then you should reduce \$R_{SET}\$:

$$ R_{SET} = \frac{V_2}{I} = = \frac{1V}{11A} = 90m\Omega $$

Alternatively raise \$V_2\$:

$$ V_2 = I \times R_{SET} = 11A \times 0.5\Omega = 5.5V $$

Since \$V_2\$ will appear across \$R_{SET}\$, you can calculate the power that \$R_{SET}\$ will dissipate. Assuming \$V_2=+5.5V\$:

$$ P_{RSET} = \frac{{V_2}^2}{R_{SET}} = \frac{(5.5V)^2}{0.5\Omega} = 60W $$

Remember that whatever voltage is across \$R_{SET}\$ is voltage *not* available for the load. Under a full 11A load, and with a supply of 48V, the maximum possible voltage across the load will be:

$$ V_{MAX(11A)} = 48V - 5.5V \approx 42V $$

I do not know how stable that closed loop system will be. \$R_{FB}\$ and \$C_F\$ provide frequency compensation for the loop, and it may be sufficient for a slightly reactive load like the one shown, but just be aware that the greater the inductance of the load, the more likely is that you end up with some nasty oscillations.

---

#### Update

Here's a simpler current limiting design:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcVD7H.png)</sup>

Here Q2 is the throttle, triggered when the voltage across R1 reaches about 0.7V, which switches on Q1, causing Q2's gate potential to rise. R1 therefore determines the maximum current available to the load, according to:

$$ I_{MAX} \approx \frac{0.7V}{R_1} $$

As you can see, the load is passing over 10A, and has over 10V across it. Most of the remaining 25V must appear across Q2, also passing those 10A, which is why it is dissipating 260W.

You have two solutions to this problem:

1. Lower the supply voltage to be closer to the expected voltage across the load, when it's at maximum current. The output voltage will remain the same, but the pass transistor Q2 will have much less potential difference between input and output to "consume".
2. Split the current through several pass transistors. That might look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvcdNZ.png)</sup>

Resistors R4, R5 and R6 are "ballast" to balance out any mismatch between \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ of the three MOSFETs.

Of course, you can employ both of the above ideas simultaneously: reduce supply voltage *and* share the load current between multiple transistors.