# Power dissipation of PCB trace resistor in current limiting application

Tags: pcb, resistors, power-dissipation

How to I calculate the width of a PCB trace to survive use as a current limiting sense resistor?

I'm looking at a low-side current limiting application like that shown in the schematic. The value of `Rset` that I actually want is ~90e-3 based on this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/679478/8376). I have found an [online calculator](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/trace-resistance-calculator/) that allows me to estimate resistance for a given trace. It also shows how the resistance varies with temperature. Where I'm stumped is how wide to make the trace so the temperature doesn't rocket and go significantly over, say 0.1 ohm (or just burn like a fuse). The circuit driven with PWM. There are bursts of 11A from the 48V supply, but the RMS power that needs to be dissipated will be much, much lower.

[image]

Is there a system of equations (or rules of thumb) to simulate this in its basic form? What would the rate of temperature increase be across this trace during the brief pulses of peak power and over time. Basically how can I estimate peak and continuous power dissipation.

Would the performance of a low resistance SMD resistor be significantly better in any way? I guess normally yes, but with such a low resistance I'm wondering if I can drop an item from the BOM.

Comment: Why can't you use a current sense resistor?

Comment: I could, but this is such a small resistance I was just wondering if its worth adding another component?

Comment: 90mΩ is a huge resistance to make from (nearly) pure copper. Even single ~mΩ are troublesome, because of power density, layout area, tolerance, tempco, stray inductance, etc.

Comment: https://passive-components.eu/current-sense-resistor-selection-tradeoffs

"As the needed resistance value in so many designs is so small  it may seem that a quick, easy, and “free” solution to having a sense resistor is to just use a short length of the PC-board copper trace, with its size calculated to provide that exact resistance value. However, ordinary copper, such as used for PC cladding, has a typical tempco of 0.4%/°C, which means any self-heating will result in large drift and errors. Thus, the PC-board trace technique is only used where accuracy demands are very loose